# Puzzle: Oscillating Rope and a Spring!

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

Here's a **puzzle** one of my friends in physics class gave me -

Consider a uniform rope suspended from the ceiling with the help of a spring. At what distance from the lower end (fraction of total length of the rope), the rope can be cut so that the portion hanging from the spring **oscillates remaining straight**?

Initially, I thought it doesn't matter from where the rope is cut - for there will always be a restoring force upwards. This restoring force would be responsible for the oscillations.  However, to my surprise, he said the answer to the puzzle is to cut *less than half* the rope's length, so that the remaining part *oscillates remaining straight*.

What's going on here? Could someone help me out? I'm not able to understand why there should be a restriction on how much length is cut, for there'll always be a restoring force upwards after the portion is cut. Is something else going on here, probably because the rope is attached to a spring?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean when you say "suspended with the help of a spring" and "oscillate remaining straight".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s a rope hanging, with it’s weight supported by a stretched spring. It’s in equilibrium.

When you cut a tiny bit off, it’s suddenly out of equilibrium: the weight has decreased by $\lambda \Delta L g$ so the spring is stretched by $\lambda \Delta L g/k$ too much. So the system will oscillate with that amplitude and frequency $\sqrt{k \over{(L - \Delta L) \lambda}}$ and peak acceleration $A\omega^2 = (\lambda \Delta L g/k) {k\over{(L - \Delta L) \lambda}} = {\Delta L \over {L - \Delta L}}g$

As you cut more, the amplitude gets bigger. And so does the resulting peak acceleration.

Eventually, that peak acceleration will be more than $g$.  That’s not a problem on the way up; the spring just pulls hard. But it is a problem on the way down, because you can’t push on a string: it can’t fall fast enough to keep tension in it.

That happens when the acceleration is $g$ or more: $\Delta L \ge L/2$